# Is there a quick way to remove and collect a minecart tracks used for a Sky Rail?

Tags: terraria

So when i started this large world i created a whole lot of minecart tracks to make a Sky Rail to help locate the Sky Islands. Now i want to tear it down as i got what i wanted but also i want to move it underground but i'm finding it that it's taking longer to take down than to put up.

When i was putting it up i only needed to go at a set speed then just hold the minecart track out in front. i can't do the same as even with the Molten Pickaxe if i go more than 4 mph i end up skipping a track and it's at around 5 mph that the minecart will start to move on it's own.

So i am wondering if there is a quick way to remove and collect the minecart tracks i used for my Sky Rail

Answer (score 10):

### You need to increase your [Mining Speed](https://terraria.gamepedia.com/Mining_speed)

> Mining speed .. is an invisible statistic that determines how fast the player can mine

Basically even with better tools, you will always break (low-tier) blocks with "1 hit", but if you increase your mining speed, you can hit more blocks per second.
Molten pickaxe has the second **slowest** mining speed in the game, since you aren't in hardmode yet (I guess?), there are few thing that you can do to increase your mining speed (rather than get a better pickaxe):

- Downgrade your pickaxe to get a faster one (while still breaking with 1 hit). For comparison here are the mining speed for some pre-hardmode pickaxes (lower is better) <sup>Full pickaxe list with their speeds can be found [here](https://terraria.gamepedia.com/Pickaxes)</sup>

  - Silver Pickaxe - 11
  - Deathbringer Pickaxe - 14
  - Nightmare Pickaxe - 15
  - Molten Pickaxe - 18
- Reforge your pickaxe to grab a prefix with a higher speed bonus.

  - Light  +15%
  - Legendary  +10%
  - Deadly  +10%
  - Agile  +10%
  - Quick  +10%
  - Nasty  +10%
  - Murderous  +6%
  - Nimble  +5%
- Use Speed-increasing buffs and items

  - The Mining buff from the Mining Potion (Bottled Water + Antlion Mandible + Blinkroot) adds 25%.
  - The set bonus of the Mining set (Mining Helmet, Mining Shirt and Mining Pants) adds 30%. All of those items can be dropped by Undead Miners. The helmet can also be bought from the merchant.
  - The Celestial Shell, Celestial Stone, The Sun Stone and Moon Stone add 15% each (hardmode-only).

> The bonus from items is capped at 70%

---

Note from personal experience: Leave the track there.

- Later you will have better tools for the job (if you still want to remove it). Faster pickaxes, Drill Containment Unit, flying mounts, etc.
- You can use it to

  - Move faster between your world jungle / spawn (center) / dungeon
  - Fight bosses